# Auto-generate documentation *only* after build workflow?

Tags: c++, github, cmake, github-actions, doxygen

I've made a habit of providing a [documentation-generating target](https://vicrucann.github.io/tutorials/quick-cmake-doxygen/) to my CMake projects, which generate a custom Doxyfile from metada stored in CMake variables (such as project name, description and version).

At the same time, documentation hosting services are very useful to acess the docs 24/7 remotely and without the need to actually generate them locally. Is there a way to configure a tool like [codedocs.xyz](https://codedocs.xyz/) to run a preliminary build workflow/action that generates this Doxyfile? Or, alternatively, ensure the documentation generation only happens after some (sucessful) build workflow?

Comment: So you want your documentation-generating target to run only if your executable (or library) is successfully built? Similar to how your executable (or library) target is built only if your source files are successfully compiled?

Comment: I think you probably need something like the cmake `config_files` to generate the Doxyfile.

Comment: @JaMiT Not really, Ideally I want codedocs.xyz (for instance, I'm open to suggestions on alternatives) to only build documentation *after* a build workflow is sucessful. I can configure a specific Doxyfile to be used, but I don't have any way of ensuring it waits for a new/updated Doxyfile, as it runs on different servers.

Comment: I suspect this may not be possible with third party tools as I describe it, perhaps only using something like GitHub pages - but I'm limited to a single page if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You may be able to use `add_dependencies(doxygenTarget cmakeLibTarget)` to make sure `cmakeLibTarget` is built before `doxygenTarget`...

Comment: @joaocandre Sorry, I'm lost. Could you explain the difference between *"[build documentation] only if your [target] is successfully built"* (what I wrote) and *"only build documentation* after *a build workflow is sucessful"* (what you wrote). You put emphasis on "after", but that seems basically synonymous with "if" in this context. (You cannot determine the "if" until after the build.)

Comment: @JaMiT you are correct, but your comment stated *documentation-generating target to run*. I don´t necessarily want it to run, I want third-party services like codedocs.xyz to build documentation only after a successful build.

Comment: @joaocandre OK, I guess I don't understand what your target is supposed to do. It looked to me like the target was supposed to cause your third-party services like codedocs.xyz to build documentation. I guess not? Or maybe you're just hung up that I typed "run" when I could have typed "build"? (I meant "run" in the sense that cmake runs the process to build the target, not in the sense of running the thing that gets built.) Either way, I'll leave this to others.

Comment: The CMake target just calls doxygen locally (I linked how it's set up in the question). Services like codedocs.xyz do it, and host it, remotely, using the code on the repo. I can configure a github workflow to generate a new Doxyfile, but I can't (up to my knowledge) configure it to wait for sucessful builds on github's part.